# Having trouble producing body of spaceship

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm having trouble producing the correct output. I've gotten the top part of the body produced, but can't get the bottom part. It is pretty much the flipped over version of it. This is the output I am trying to get:

```
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
```

code:

```
public static void Body() {
    for (int f = 1; f <= 3; f++) {
        System.out.print("|");

        for (int g = 1; g <= 3 - f; g++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }            

        for (int h = 1; h <= f; h++) {
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3-f; i++) {
            System.out.print("..");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= f; j++) {
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }

        for (int h = 1; h <= 3 - f; h++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();      
    }
}

public static void Body2() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("|");

        for (int j = 1; j <= 3 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }            

        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print("\\/");
        }

        for (int l = 1; l <= 3-i; l++) {
            System.out.print("..");
        }

        for (int m = 1; m <= i; m++) {
            System.out.print("\\/");
        }

        for (int n = 1; n <= 3 - i; n++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();      
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can't show the desired output for some reason. Can anyone point me in the right direction to somehow show it? It's various characters.

Comment: Indent every line four spaces. You can select the whole thing and click the `{}` formatting button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the outer `for` loop in `body2()` method from `i = 3 to i > 0` to get the desired output. You don't need to change any of the inner `for` loops of your `body2()` method:

```
public static void body2() {
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print("|");

        for (int j = 1; j <= 3 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print("\\/");
        }

        for (int l = 1; l <= 3 - i; l++) {
            System.out.print("..");
        }

        for (int m = 1; m <= i; m++) {
            System.out.print("\\/");
        }

        for (int n = 1; n <= 3 - i; n++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked. Can you explain to me the logic behind why it worked though? I still don't fully get it.

Comment: @EverythingAndNothing you are welcome. i think you have understood what `body()` is doing. And `body2()` should print the chars exactly in the reverse order (changing /\ to \/), printing `\/` in the first line. As `body()` prints all /\ in the last line `(for i=3)`, so if you iterate the loop from `i=3 to 1`, it will print all `\/` in the first line `(for i=3)`. And same goes for other chars and lines.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! I think I kind of get it, I'll have to look into for loops and nested loops in general more.

Comment: @EverythingAndNothing: I think it would be very useful for you to go through line by line and draw the output on paper. It will help you immensely in understanding how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your static methods Body and Body2 are doing the same things. Do you want Body2 to be the flipped over version of Body? If so you could change the strings it's outputting to get it right, pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes, that's how I want to do it. I'm unsure how to do it though, I already really struggled with Body and had a lot of help from a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, I can't test it just yet:

```
public static void Body2() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("|");

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }            

        for (int k = 1; k <= 3 - i; k++) {
            System.out.print("\\/");
        }

        for (int l = 1; l <= i; l++) {
            System.out.print("..");
        }

        for (int m = 1; m <= i; m++) {
            System.out.print("\\/");
        }

        for (int n = 1; n <= i; n++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();      
    }
```

I have basically just swapped your `3 - i` with `i`, and your `i` with `3 - i`.

Comment: Thanks for posting! I tried the code, and it still doesn't output right for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your output? Edit: never mind you already got a solution.